# MPMoviePlayerController view orientation differs on iphone 3g and 4g

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm trying to play fullscreen landscape video in .m4v format on iPhone using MPMoviePlayerController in my cocos2d game. On 4g device everything works well, but on 3g the video has screen dimensions but vertical orientation, so I can only see the left side of the movie. I'm not sure if the problem is with MPMoviePlayerController or with cocos2d gl view. Here's my code:

```
    NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"intro" ofType:@"m4v"];
    player = [[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]] retain];

    [player.view setFrame: [[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView].bounds]; 
    if ([player respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)]) {  
        // Use the new 3.2 style API  
        player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;  
        player.shouldAutoplay = YES;  
        CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];  
        CGRect rScreen;
        rScreen.origin.x = 0;
        rScreen.origin.y = 0;
        rScreen.size.width = winSize.width;
        rScreen.size.height = winSize.height;
        player.view.frame = rScreen;  
    } else {
        // Use the old 2.0 style API  
        player.movieControlMode = MPMovieControlModeHidden;  
    } 
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:player.view];  
    [player play];
```

How to make video play well on 3g device? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Where exactly does this code run? If it's in the didFinishLaunching method or the first scene's init method then it might be a simple case of running this code "too early". It would also be interesting to know which iOS version the 3G is running.

Comment: the orientation is wrong on iphone 3g 4.2.1. The same is on another 3g, not sure what version. This code is executed in 3rd scene, after play button is tapped and level is chosen. FYI - if I add this string `[player.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((float)M_PI_2)];`, the orientation is Ok on 3g but is wrong on 4g. :(